# Should I use the "die" idiom in C++?

Tags: c++, error-handling, idioms, exit-strategy, cross-language

If we implement the following function:

```
template <typename... Ts>
[[noreturn]] inline bool die(std::string_view message_format = "", Ts&&... args);
```

We can then write:

```
if (bad_thing_happened()) die("A bad thing happened!");
```

or, for example

```
things_are_ok() or die("Things are not ok, and foo is {}", foo);
```

I know this idiom from [perl](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/the-unless-and-die-function-in-perl) (which also has `unless`, making such expressions more natural-language like: `die("oh no") unless (things_are_ok())`). Is it a good idea to use this idiom in C++?

**Note**: I'm only asking about code where it makes sense to terminate the application. If `std::exit()` is inappropriate, naturally so is a `die()` command.

Comment: As I understand the rationale behind `die`, programming languages like Perl and PHP create individual web pages by running a script in a process. Writing `die` essentially means "The web page has been sufficiently rendered, I no longer have any use for you, script."  

It's hard to imagine there being much benefit to such a mechanism in C++ when C++ is not commonly used to build web pages, especially when so much attention is paid to managing memory gracefully in C++.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: `die()` predates the WWW... it's not an HTTP-specific or even networking-specific construct. `die()` is for a process on a Unix-like system.

Comment: Same rationale in any case.  "I no longer have any use for this process."  It's a good thing well-behaved operating systems clean up after processes' allocated memory automatically.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: So, why is this hard to imagine? Isn't it the same rationale as exit(), terminate() and abort()?

Comment: Are those things really widely used?  Seems like the "abandon hope, all ye who enter here" approach.  `goto` still exists; doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: 1. Sure they are... 2. Why would you `goto` someplace which exits, when you can just exit?

Comment: Is this a question, or a debate?  If it's a debate, there are better places on the Internet for that sort of thing, like Reddit.

Comment: The question is closed now, but it doesn't seem a good idea to try to make languages looking more like natural languages.  And abruptly aborting a C++ programme like that might not be a good idea if using RAII if some system resources would be at risk of not being released as expected.  The C++ core guidelines say ["***if you can't throw an exception**, consider failing fast*"](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#e26-if-you-cant-throw-exceptions-consider-failing-fast) but this idiom encourages not to consider exceptions in the first place.

Comment: @Christophe: It's enough of a good idea to merit 3 explicit standard library functions. But it's true that the stack is not unwound, so that, in principle, allocated out-of-process resources may remain orphaned.

Comment: The existence of something (or even 3 of the same thing) doesn't automatically make it good.  Quite the opposite; the fact that there are three ways to do the same thing suggests that none of them is ideal.

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9390/118878).

Comment: The use of the word `die` is not what you usually see in C++ but there's nothing wrong with it.  One nice thing about this kind of fail-fast routine is you can do some interesting things in `die()` just before you exit the process, e.g., emit a stacktrace.  But more idiomatic C++ to wrap an `assert` statement with some kind of  - typically spelled "assert" but with different _capitalization_ - and use that instead of an if statement.  You'd use `Assert(<conditional-expression>, <message>, <optional-args-to-message>)` or maybe even ...

Comment: ... `Assert(<conditional-expression>, <output-expression-using-stream-output-operators>` (where this `Assert` is implemented as a macro) which would look like `Assert(still_looking_good(), "bad thing happened" << foo << ", " << bar")` for variables `foo` and `bar` for which `operator<<(ostream&, T)` is defined.

Comment: @davidbak: "assert" suggests that you are certain that the condition will be met; and that you will only check it in debug builds.

Comment: @einpoklum - you're right that `assert` is used for debug builds - consider instead using `verify` or something.  But yes, you assert the condition is held, not `if (the bad thing happens)` - i'm just suggesting it is more common in C++, when checking a condition, to specify that it must be true rather than check that it is false.

Comment: By any chance, are you a German speaker and are you referring to `this`? [relevant link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gaXigSu72A4)

Comment: @Flater: I know just about enough German to say: "Nein, Ich sprechen nicht Deutch" and I'm not even sure that's quite correct... but thanks for die nostalgic clip :-)

Comment: @DocBrown: `or` is perfectly valid C++.

Comment: @einpoklum: I guess you are right. I can't believe I missed that, since I am using C++ now since 1994 and never saw code with "or", only "||"

Comment: @DocBrown: Weird... Anyway, this actually relates to the question's content - the potential for an idiom which looks and sounds somewhat like a sentence in English.

Answer (score 4):

I can imagine two implementations of `die`, and I have issue with both of them

```
template <typename... Ts>
[[noreturn]] inline bool die(std::string_view message_format = "", Ts&&... args)
{
    std::cerr << std::vformat(message_format, std::make_format_args(args...));
    std::abort(); // or std::exit or std::terminate
}
```

That is, write the message somewhere and end the program. I could imagine a project using this, but not the projects I'm involved in.

It  seems most appropriate in projects large enough that you don't just `return` up to `main`, but small enough that killing the whole process is never overkill.

```
template <typename... Ts>
[[noreturn]] inline bool die(std::string_view message_format = "", Ts&&... args)
{
    throw std::runtime_error(std::vformat(message_format, std::make_format_args(args...)));
}
```

I.e. throw a generic exception, with the message. I would prefer some granularity in the type of the exception, so that `args...` could instead be a data member for the `catch`. If pressed, i'd write that as

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
[[noreturn]] inline bool die_with(Args&&... args)
{
    throw T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

things_are_ok() or die_with<things_exception>("things not ok", foo);
```

But there are other ways of massaging a `throw` to be a `bool` expression

```
things_are_ok() or (throw things_exception("things not ok", foo), false);
```

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of the first version, although with [`std::exit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit). An exception might be caught, and I want `die()` to actually do what it says. But thanks for emphasizing this point.

Comment: @einpoklum `std::abort`, `std::exit` or `std::terminate` would be interchangeable for the purpose of this answer

Comment: Fair enough, edited that in.

Comment: Your second `die` just obfuscates `throw things_exception("things not ok", foo);`, and is thus a net drain. (Though it can be used as a callback, and `try` itself cannot.) Also, good on you to fix the format-strings type.

Comment: @Deduplicator it's a bool expression, rather than a throw expression. You could do similar with `throw blah... , false`

Comment: use when exceptions "make you give in and cry"?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Yes, I've changed that too. I copied from non-C++17 code.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a good idea to use this idiom in C++?

No.

Exit (or terminate, or abort, or die) is not something you should use in C++. There are cases when it is useful, but those are special cases (special as in "we are working at a nuclear power plant and need to guarantee the application is exited *NOW* - as in *RIGHT NOW DAMMIT!*").

To interrupt process flow in a normal application, it is better to throw an exception.

Comment: 1. Why is  it "better" to exit using an exception?. 2. In many scenarios, use of exceptions is unacceptable. 3. Sometimes you need to exit while handling an exception.

Comment: 1. because there are situations when you decide to interupt your application flow (exit) but client code may decide to handle the error. Exitting does not allow for that option. 2. I have worked in a few projects like that (not using exceptions because they were unacceptable) - the reasoning for not using exceptions was always bogus (the arguments were superficial). 3. If you need to exit while handling the exception, that should be decided _while handling the exception_, not while raising the exception. Many places that signal an error condition do not know how to handle the error themselves.

Comment: 1. I'm not sure what you mean by "client code". If you mean when writing a library, then I certainly agree, but otherwise - I'm the "client". 2. The reasoning for using exception is not "always bogus"; often, it's not even possible, and there are no stack, no interrupt, etc. 3. So, assume my question is about code in an exception handler.

Answer (score 1):

In library code, no. Library code should cause the application to terminate only on the most severe logic errors, something that should never happen (like memory self-corrupting). And if you do this termination, you should at least leave behind a core dump. Even then, throwing an exception specifically designed for severe logic errors wouldn't be a bad idea though, because an unhandled exception will anyway terminate the application, and presumably that exception wouldn't be handled anyway (if bits are flipping randomly, there's no sane way to handle the exception -- on the other hand, if bits are flipping randomly it could be that some exception handler flipped randomly to handle your severe logic error -- but there's also the problem that if bits are flipping randomly, you can't trust your core dump).

However, in application code, only the application author knows. In complex applications, where lot of the code is actually per-application library code, you should probably consider that code similar to generic library code. However, in simple <1000-liner applications it's possible that your error handling strategy is simply exiting. And even if that strategy changes at some point of time, you shouldn't have too much code to rewrite. In any case, some "die" function is far better choice than printing and error message and exiting, because you can easily search for all users of "die" and change them to throw an exception instead -- or maybe you want to just edit the "die" function to throw an exception.

Comment: In library code, I wouldn't exit anyway. Let me clarify this in the question.